# PDE problem for 1D

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Suppose u is a smooth solution of the following problem:
>
> $u_{xxt}+u_{xx}−u^3 =0 $ in $[0,1]×(0,∞)$,
>
> $u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0 $ $\forall t \geq 0$
>
> with initial data $u(x, 0) = x(x − 1)$.Show that $u(x,t)$ uniformly tends to zero as $t → \infty$.

Actually I think I have to use energy method with $E(t) = \int_{0}^{1}(u_x)^{2}(x,t)dt$, but don't know how. Could you give me some hint for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the equation by $u$ and integrate by parts in space:
$$
\int u_xu_{xt}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\|u\|_{H^1}^2=-\int u_x^2-u^4\leq -\|u\|_{H^1}^2
$$
Consequently, using Sobolev embedding,
$$
\|u(t)\|_{L^\infty}\leq c\|u(t)\|_{H^1}\leq \|u_0\|_{H^1}e^{-t}
$$
Right?

Comment: Oh.. Integrate by parts.. Thank you! Actually I don't know what the sobolev embedding is, but I can get it with the energy method.

Comment: By Sobolev embedding I mean the inequality 
$\|u\|_{L^\infty}\leq c\|u\|_{H^1}$